# Why won't this save my changes? Or is it not copying?

Tags: c#, com, excel-2010, excel-interop

So, all I'm trying to do is copy over every cell from one Excel doc to another, with the intent of preventing a user to upload a file containing macros onto my server. When I run this through with a test form it asks me where to save the "Clean" document, but it appears as though no changes were made to it, except the timestamp...

```
object objMissing = Missing.Value;
Excel.Workbook xlDirtyWorkbook = xlDirtyApp.Workbooks.Open(strDirtyDocPath,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objTrue,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing);
Excel.Worksheet xlDirtyWorksheet = 
      (Excel.Worksheet)xlDirtyWorkbook.Worksheets[1];

Excel.Workbook xlCleanWorkbook = xlCleanApp.Workbooks.Open(strCleanDocPath,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objTrue,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                            objMissing, objMissing);
Excel.Worksheet xlCleanWorksheet = 
      (Excel.Worksheet)xlCleanWorkbook.Worksheets[1];

// -- Copy User Modifiable Range --
Excel.Range rnThisDirtyCell = xlDirtyWorksheet.get_Range("A2:L310", objMissing);
Excel.Range rnThisCleanCell = xlCleanWorksheet.get_Range("A2:L310", objMissing);

rnThisDirtyCell.Copy(rnThisCleanCell);

// -- Copy Document Meta-Data --
object dpDirtyProps;
object dpCleanProps;

dpDirtyProps = xlDirtyWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties;
dpCleanProps = xlCleanWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties;

dpCleanProps = dpDirtyProps;
```

Frankly, I'm not even certain if it's opening the file. The workbook Identity value is null. I'm passing a valid path for both workbooks. I'm using the full path including file name in the Application.Worksheets.Open method. Is this not correct?

What am I missing? It's not throwing any exceptions...

==================================================================================

For posterity, this is how I solved it:

```
Excel.Workbook xlDirtyWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strDirtyDocPath,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, true,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing);

Excel.Workbook xlCleanWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strCleanTemplatePath,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, true,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                 objMissing, objMissing);

for (int iIndex = 1; iIndex <= xlDirtyWorkbook.Worksheets.Count; iIndex++ )
{
    rnThisDirtyCell = xlDirtyWorkbook.Worksheets[iIndex].UsedRange;
    rnThisCleanCell = xlCleanWorkbook.Worksheets[iIndex].Range(
        rnThisDirtyCell.Address);
    rnThisDirtyCell.Copy(rnThisCleanCell);
}
```

Comment: why not just save it as an `.XLSX` (macro free workbook)?

Comment: Well, there are macros on the form that need to be there, I just want to ensure on upload there are no adulterated macros. So I'm trying to copy cell by cell the uploaded document to a copy of the original distributed template document. I'm also trying to preserve any formatting/style changes on the cells from the uploaded document, and maintain these in the copied version (with the macros in the background that I know for sure are legitimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was running two instances of excel.exe, loading one workbook into each. Loading both workbooks in the same Application instance solved my problem.